# Create a realtime observer in Firebase that always updates changes using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a function that will update my tableview whenever changes are made to the database.

[image]

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            self.refreshData() // REFRESH for New Task Created
        })

Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks").observeSingleEvent(of: .childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            self.refreshData() // REFRESH for Task Deleted
        })

Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks").observeSingleEvent(of: .childChanged, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            self.refreshData() // REFRESH for Task Edited
        })
```

The above observers that I call in my viewDidLoad() don't catch most changes made and stop working completely shortly after the project runs. How can I fix this / is there a better, working observe function that can update labels if changed are made and update my tableview if rows are deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is using `.observeSingleEvent(of:`, which (as its name implies) observes a single event of the type and then stops listening.

To keep listening for changes after the initial event, us `observe`, so:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks")
        .observe( .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
           ...
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events).